# Корзина товаров на чистом js: ООП или функциональный стиль?

Tags: javascript, ооп, функциональное-программирование

Пишу сайт, на котором присутствует возможность выбирать товары и добавлять их в корзину. Я пробовал писать JavaScript класс для корзины, но проблема в том, что меняющихся данных слишком много и их нужно постоянно вручную перерендеривать.

Добавлять взаимодействие с DOM в класс мне кажется странным, так как изначальная задумка была в чисто классе для работы с данными без DOM. И пока что мне кажется правильным использовать обычные функции, с отдельными функциями для рендера и работы с данными.

Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: Твоя программа - тебе и решать. Все равно больше чем ты можешь, ты не сделаешь...

Comment: Сделай в ООП по шаблону MVC